# Creating second customized POM in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

Within a maven project under eclipse, I want to have a second(or customized) pom.xml in which I can use plugings like the [assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

The problem with this plugin is that it requieres an outputh path which is only interesting for me.

Since I'm using git to push to a remote repository, I don't want to pollute the version controlled pom.xml with my private paths and other stuff.

I read about inheritance and multi-mode possibilities, but I only need two poms:

1) One for the public with general settings

2) One only for me with cusotimzed build options

I tried to create a second pom file and wanted to build the project with a new run configuration, but I don't know how to pass the -f parameter(which should call a different pom) in that dialog.

Thanks for hints or best practices.

Example of what I want to put in the custom pom:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version> 
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>some\private\path</outputDirectory>
        <finalName>SomeName</finalName>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you show examples of what you like to put into such customize pom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the second POM in the Package Explorer, right click -> Run As -> Maven Build...

That should run Maven with the custom POM.

If you don't get the Maven options in the "Run As" menu, go to the "Content Types" preferences page -> Text -> XML -> Maven POM XML.

Add the name of your custom POM so Eclipse understands that this is also a POM (I'm not 100% sure it will look inside a file to determine the type).

If that also fails, you can use a trick: Write a small tool that takes the unmodified POM, adds the XML which you need and then runs Maven. On Linux, you can use shell scripts for that. On Windows, a small Java program might be easier. Or have a look at PowerShell.

Comment: I tried that but maven tells me it cannot find pom.xml. The second's name is pom2.xml in the same folder. How to tell maven to use that one?

Comment: The most simple solution for you is to run Maven from the command line. To answer your question: My guess is the developers of m2e didn't consider that someone might want to use different POMs in a single project, so the file name is fixed. But then, I don't understand why you can say "cannot find pom.xml". Does it run the normal POM? Or do you get an error.

Comment: I do not use the plugin, but I also don't want to switch to command line all the time. As an alternative I could create a separate project with the tailored pom.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all. How do you execute Maven when you're not using Eclipse, m2e or the command line?

Comment: Within the plugin options one can specifiy to use a local installation. Preferences->Maven->Installation

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I do not use the plugin"? Which "plugin" specifically? Is it a plugin for Maven or for Eclipse? Furthermore, give me the exact steps what you do in Eclipse to start the assembly plugin and the exact error message.